# Rails test job and raise errors if any

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a job, which I'm currently testing using RSpec:

```
# app/jobs/do_something_job.rb
class DoSomethingJob < ApplicationJob
  def perform(a, b, c)
    Service.new(a, b, c).call
  end
end
```

The example file looks this way:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe DoSomethingJob do
  it do
    expect { described_class.perform_later(a, b, c) }.to have_enqueued_job
  end
end
```

That example certainly succeeds, it queues the job no matter what happens within the `perform` method body.

Now if I update the `Service` class, like removing an argument on its `initialize` method, leaving this way:

```
class Service
  def initialize(a, b)
    ...
  end
end
```

And I don't update the job example, it'll anyway succeed because the job is enqueued. What I'm trying to do is to test the body of `DoSomethingJob#perform` executes without errors, without getting on the specifics of `Service` itself (it has its own tests).

I tried mocking Service and using `expect { ... }.not_to raise_error`, but that fakes the test, since I have to stub the `new` and `call` methods it receives.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried using `perform_now` just for the sake of testing? It's equivalent to `perform_later`, but instead of enqueuing, it runs instantially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a class method on the service so that you don't have to stub  an instance:

```
class Service
  def self.call(a, b, c)
     new(a, b, c).call
  end
end

# app/jobs/do_something_job.rb
class DoSomethingJob < ApplicationJob
  def perform(a, b, c)
    Service.call(a, b, c)
  end
end
```

Then simply place an expectation on what you want the method to do (in this case call the collaborator) and perform the job immediately:

```
describe DoSomethingJob do
  it "calls Service with a, b, c" do
    expect(Service).to receive(:call).with(1, 2, 3).and_call_original
    DoSomethingJob.perform_now(1, 2, 3)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I can do the same without having to create `Service#call`, isn't it?

Comment: @JohannEsburgo you would have to stub the new method so that it returns a double or use any_instance which is smelly. This kind of method is pretty much boilerplate in any kind of service object and you would usually just implement it once  in the superclass as a method that just forwards all its arguments - it gives a better API so that the consumers don't have deal with instanciating the service object.